# How to create single report from multiple data tables

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

I am not from IT major (material engineering tbh), pardon me if my question is not really clear.

I am currently studying the MS Access 2013, and right now creating a table
with details in:

[image: Table details].

The structure of the table is here:

```
+----+--------+---------+--------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| ID |  Order |  Vendor |  Attachments |  Customer |  AWB no |  Due Date |
+----+--------+---------+--------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

I created a new form, added a button to open this form and created report with macros, and used it to create a report.

I want to create a report only using data from 1 row of the table, but instead the report contains all data from table, just like the normal report.

Any suggestion how to make 1 report from only data from 1 row?

Please see this for report example:

[image: Report template]

Update : I tried to follow some instructions for "print one record" and found this VBA code :

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub BttnPrint_Click()
Dim strReportName As String
Dim StrCriteria As String

If NewRecord Then
    MsgBox "This record contains no data, Please select a record to print or save this record" _
         , vbInformation, "Invalid Action"
    Exit Sub

Else
strReportName = "REPORT"

 StrCriteria = "[ID]= " & Me![ID]

       DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewPreview, , StrCriteria
   End If

End Sub
```

This code embedded in the "print" button on the form. This code can create report based on only one record, however I cannot switch to another record, stuck in one record only no matter which record I open. What should I do if I want to create report for another records?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are creating 3 identical tables, perhaps I am not understanding your scenario. But you can select the data gathered and also which tables to get the data from by using the Create -> ***Form Wizard*** tool.

From what I can see from the table data given, your database should have around 5 tables.

tbl_Customers (id, name, surname ... further customer details) 
tbl_Orders(id, customer_id, date ... further order details) 
tbl_Attachments(id, price, vendor_id... further attachments details) 
tbl_Order_Attachments(id, order_id, attachment_id, quantity... further desired details) 
tbl_Vendors(id, name, ... further vendor details)

Comment: Thanks Dylan for the corrections, it is a column, not tables.
And the customer, orders, etc is the row.

Comment: Did you manage to create the form you desired using the Form Wizard ?

Comment: yes i manage to create the template, but the problem is the report contains all the data from all columns inside the table. So i try to create form on with dialog style hoping to just limit the data into one column, create macros to link the dialog box with the column, and add print button. However, still all the column appears on the report, not just one column. any advise?

Comment: From what I understand, you basically want to query your data. My suggestion is using simple SQL Statements. Using the WHERE clause should help you get your desired outcome.

Perhaps this link would help -> [WHERE clause in Microsoft Access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WHERE-Clause-23b55905-7d27-458a-9352-bef126e4c0b1)

Answer (score 0):

To open the report make a button in your form and use the event "on click" and write this code:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport report_name, acViewPreview, , condition"
```

eg. :

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_Demo", acViewPreview, , "City='London'"
```

Make sure you write two colons  after the word **acViewPreview**  .

In the condition field you can select your own criteria.

Comment: The question is not very clearly formulated but I guess that your answer is not what original poster wanted.